# JavaScript neglecting the else statement

Tags: javascript

I created a function which takes in two values.. 
Both are numbers represented by n & p. What the function does is that it gets the number n and splits it up then squares it to the value of p and sums them in an increasing order like this: n^p + n^(p+1) + n^(p+2) + ...

Here is the function

```
  function digPow(n, p) {
      // ...
      let num = n.toString();
      let pow = p;

      let arrn = [];
      let arrp = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
          arrn.push(JSON.parse(num[i]));
      }
      let index = arrn.join('');
      let sindex = index.split('');

      for (let j = 0; j < sindex.length; j++) {
          let power = p + j;
          let indexs = sindex[j];
          let Mathpow = Math.pow(indexs, power);
          arrp.push(Mathpow);
      }

      let total = 0;
      for (let m in arrp) {
          total += arrp[m]
      }

      let secondVal = total / n;
      let totals = total / secondVal;
      let mx = [-1]

      if (totals.length == n.length) {
          return secondVal
      } else {
          return -1
      }
  }
```

Now i created variables and arrays to store up the values and then the if part is my problem.. The if/else statement is meant to let the program check if a particular variable `totals` is equal to `n` which is the input.. if true it should return a variable `secondVal` and if not it should return `-1`..

So far its only returning `secondVal` and i'snt returning `-1` in cases where it should like:

`digPow(92, 1)` instead it returns `0.14130434782608695`

What do i do?

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: `totals` and `n` are both numbers, not arrays. Why are you comparing their length: `if(totals.length == n.length){`?

Comment: You seem to be doing some very strange things here... Why are you using `JSON.parse`, for example, on what appears to be single characters??

Comment: The expected answer should be -1 @ Nina Scholz

Comment: that is meant to be `total == n` and besides its still returning the wrong value @DanielBeck

Comment: ...and that whole loop with the JSON.parse ends up just laboriously reconstructing the same thing as `n`:  Take a number, convert it to a string, separate each character into an array, join the array back into a string, then split it into an array again?  I think you need to  rethink  the logic here; start by stripping out the parts that don't do anything and see what's left.

Comment: I used `JSON.parse` there because the character was initially a string so am converting it to a number @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: And you couldn't just use `Number()`? Or even just `+` unary operator?

Comment: @EzeokeWill you convert each digit to a number, then glue them all back together as a string with the `.join('')` call. It really doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Hmmm... Thinking

Answer (score 0):

`totals` and `n` are both numbers. They don't have a `.length` property, so both `totals.length` and `n.length` evaluate to `undefined`. Thus, they are equal to each other.

There are plenty of other weird things going on in your code, too. I'd recommend finding a good JavaScript tutorial and working through it to get a better feel for how the language (and programming in general) works.

Comment: Any recommendations? @llmariKaronen

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by stripping out the redundant variables and circular-logic code from your function:

```
function digPow(n, p) {
  let num = n.toString();
  // let pow = p;   // this is never used again
  // let arrn = []; // not needed, see below
  // let arrp = []; // was only used to contain values that are later summed; can instead just sum them in the first place 

  // this does the same thing as num.split(''), and isn't needed anyway:
  //for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  //  arrn.push(JSON.parse(num[i]));
  //}

  // this is the same as the original 'num' variable
  // let index = arrn.join(''); 

  // This could have been num.split(), but isn't needed anyway
  // let sindex = index.split('');


  let total = 0; // moved this line here from after the loop below:

  for (let j = 0; j < num.length; j++) { // use num.length instead of the redundant sindex
    let power = p + j;
    // The only reason for the sindex array was to get individual characters from the string, which we can do with .charAt().
    //let indexs = sindex[j];
    let indexs = num.charAt(j);
    let Mathpow = Math.pow(indexs, power);
    //arrp.push(Mathpow); // No need to collect these in an array
    total += Mathpow; // do this instead
  }

  // No need for this loop, since we can sum the total during the previous loop
  // let total = 0;
  //for (let m in arrp) {
  //  total += arrp[m]
  //}

  let secondVal = total / n;
  // let totals = total / secondVal;
  // The above is the same thing as total / total / n, which is:
  let totals = 1/n;

  // This is never used
  //let mx = [-1]

  // This was totals.length and n.length, which for numbers would always be undefined, so would always return true
  if (totals == n) {
    return secondVal
  } else {
    return -1
  }
}
```

So the above reduces to this functionally identical code:

```
function digPow(n, p) {
  let num = n.toString();

  let total = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
    let power = p + j;
    let indexs = num.charAt(j);
    let Mathpow = Math.pow(indexs, power);
    total += Mathpow;
  }

  let secondVal = total / n;
  let totals = 1 / n;

  if (totals == n) {
    return secondVal
  } else {
    return -1
  }
}
```

Now let's talk about the logic.  The actual output will always be -1, unless the input is 1, due to what's clearly a logic error in the `totals` variable: the only case where 1/n == n is true is when n==1.

Setting that aside, and looking only at the `secondVal` variable, some examples of what it's calculating for a given input would be

```
digPow(123,1) -->  (1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3) / 123 --> 14/123
digPow(321,2) -->  (3^2 + 2^3 + 1^4) / 321 --> 21/321
digPow(92, 1) -->  (9^1 + 2^2) / 92        --> 13/92
```

I'm pretty sure from your description that that's not what you intended. I'm not at all sure from your description what you *did* intend, so can't be much help in correcting the function beyond what I've done here.

What I'd suggest is to sit down and think through your algorithm first; make sure you know what you're trying to build before you start building it. There were some syntax problems with your code, but the real issues are with the logic itself. Your original function shows clear signs of "just keep throwing more lines of code at it until something happens" rather than any planned thinking -- that's how you wind up with stuff like "split a string into an array, then join it back into a string, then split that string into another array".  Write pseudocode first: break the problem down into steps, think through those steps for some example inputs and make sure it'll produce the output you're looking for. Only then should you bust out the IDE and start writing javascript.